# Tag merge request: [underscore] into [underscore.js]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore)

> Underscore is a JavaScript library that adds functional programming to JavaScript

[underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js)

> Underscore is a utility-belt library for JavaScript that provides a
>   lot of the functional programming support that you would expect in
>   Prototype.js (or Ruby), but without extending any of the built-in
>   JavaScript objects. It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux.

Tags are synonymous. I feel [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js) is more accurate, and that [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) should be merged.

Comment: @Asylum I take it by your edit that `discussion` was the right way to go?

Comment: Note that there are several questions tagged `underscore` which do not refer to the JS library. From a quick glance, I see some referring to the character `_` and some refer to it as the wildcard in languages with pattern matching.

Comment: Agreed, but based on the current description of `underscore` they are mistagged.

Comment: Someone with db access could easily move all `underscore`+`javascript` questions to `underscore.js` and modify the tag description to better describe those questions.

Comment: Yes. It's not a `[bug]`, neither a `[feature-request]` and you're not looking for `[support]`. Well, such requests are tagged cross country, but I think we should stick to `[discussion]`, because it mainly is one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree and propose a mass retag + a synonym: [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) -> [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js)

*hammar (from question comments)*:

> Note that there are several questions tagged underscore which do not
>   refer to the JS library. From a quick glance, I see some referring to
>   the character _ and some refer to it as the wildcard in languages with
>   pattern matching.

Does [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) by itself (representing the `_` character) make sense as a tag, even for these few cases? I don't know who would follow it. I think it can be wiped out and synonymized with no opposition.

If [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) *does* deserve its own tag to represent the character, the logical conclusion is that we'd need a tag for *every* character, which seems asinine.

Comment: We *do* have a handful of other tags for punctuation, including [tag:dash] and [tag:hyphen] (that pair is another discussion).  Keep in mind that it's *very* difficult to search for punctuation.  The big trouble here is going to be keeping underscore.js questions in the right tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have retagged all [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) + [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) + [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js)  questions to be only [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js).

The vast majority of the ~60 questions remaining are indeed about the underscore character.  There were a few stragglers that were obviously talking about Javascript library as well.

I have also submitted a tag wiki edit that clarifies the purpose of the [underscore](/questions/tagged/underscore) tag.